# Why do I get NonExistentTimeError in python for time stamps between 12 to 1am on 2017-03-12

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone

I get this error when trying to append two Pandas DFs together in a for loop:

```
Aggdata=Aggdata.append(Newdata)
```

This is the full error:

```
File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 4096, in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas
\tslib.c:69713)
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2017-03-12 02:01:24
```

However, in my files, I do not have such a time stamp, but I do have ones like 03/12/17 00:45:26 or 03/12/17 00:01:24. Where it is 2 hours before daylight savings. And if I manually delete the offending row, I get that same error for the next row with times between 12 and 1am on the 12th of March.

My original date/time column has no TZ info, but I calculate another column in  EST, before the concatenation and localize it to EST, with time with TZ information:

```
`data['EST_DateTimeStamp']=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(da‌​ta['myDate'])).tz_lo‌​calize('US/Eastern')‌​.tz_convert('US/East‌​ern')`
```

Doing some research here, I understand that 2 to 3am on the 12th should be having such error, but why midnight to 1am. So am I localizing it incorrectly? and then why is the error on the append line, and not the localization line?

I was able to reproduce this behavior in a very simple MCVE, saved here:
https://codeshare.io/GLjrLe

It absolutely boggles my mind that the error is raised on the third append, and only if the next 3 appends follow. In others words, if I comment out the last 3 copies of appends, it works fine.. can't imagine what is happening.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What is your local TZ?

Comment: It is  EST, as I do this before the concatenation to add an EST column: data['EST_DateTimeStamp']=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(data['myDate'])).tz_localize('US/Eastern').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

Comment: If you have `00:01:24`, and the error shows `02:01:24` is nonexistent, then my guess is somewhere you are advancing the local time by two hours on the wall clock, rather than two hours of elapsed time (which would take you to `03:01:24`).  However, this is just a guess because you didn't give an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey @MattJohnson. Thanks for your note. After many long hours today of trial and error, I was able to reproduce this error in an  MCVE as you suggested. It is here: https://codeshare.io/GLjrLe

What do you think? Are you getting the same:
pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas\tslib.c:64980)()

NonExistentTimeError: 2017-03-12 02:01:24

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `tz_convert`?  You already localized the time to `US/Eastern`.  Converting from eastern to eastern should be a no-op.

Comment: Yes. Because In production code, I'm doing it dynamically in a loop for multiple DFs and from a lookup table. Actually converting to EST from various TZ. Are you saying that alone can be an issue?

Comment: @MishaAM The code you provided as MCVE is working fine on my machine. Can you update the question with your machine specs/pandas version?

Comment: @MishaAM Also your `pytz` version.

Comment: @MishaAM In utmost probability your pytz version is old so if it is just upgrade it - `pip install -U pytz`

Comment: thanks @hashcode55. I've updated pytz, same thing. And this is running (or not running) both on my work issued T450s, which has all the latest things, and a windows VM with great specs.
http://imgur.com/a/gqBsE
And yes, I just ran it again, it worked too. Seems like it does so in a random fashion. in fact, putting into a for loop, as in that pic below it breaks on the 12th iteration. Why 12th? and not 10th, or 8th? There is something weird about it. Would it work for you in a loop of 20?

Comment: Hmm weird, its still working on my machine.

Comment: Even if you do like 100 loops?

Comment: @MishaAM Yes. Whats your pandas version?

Comment: u'0.17.1'. But I guess 0.19.2 is the latest? 
I did pip upgrade, and most things were, but at the end got an error saying that I dont have admin rights.. I guess I'll need to ask IT.

Comment: But I did pip upgrade on the remote VM, and 1000 loops went fine. So I just launched the production code, see if the upgrade will help that as well!

Comment: @MishaAM Looks like the issue will be resolved. Good luck!

Comment: Yep. So worked.. a bit boring. I was hoping for a major discovery in pandas. So do you want to add this to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else may still find this helpful:

Talking about it with @hashcode55, the solution was to upgrade Pandas on my server, as this was likely a bug in my previous version of that module.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to occur at daylight savings switch - there are local times that do not exist, once per year. In the opposite direction there will be duplicate times.

This could be from say your input dates being converted from UTC to "local time" by adding a fixed offset. When you try to localize these you will hit a non existent times over that hour (or 30 minutes if you are in Adelaide).